# Can we have an option to only apply specific fields from the profile page network-wide?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

I customise my "about me" field to match each site I use, so for example, [on Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/52800/kalina) I have a list of games that I play and the types of games I'm interested in, [on Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/5603/flyk) I have a list of movies and TV shows that I watch, and on sites where I provide edits I state I'm no expert on the subject matter but that I exist to provide edits.

[image]

If I were to want to make a chance to, for example, my Display Name, Email, Website, Location, etc and apply it to all websites, because of the way the "Save And Copy Profile To All Stack Exchange Accounts" works, I would have to edit each profile individually to preserve my "About Me" sections.

Would it be possible to have a button that only applies the settings in the top half of the profile page (Display Name, Email, Real Name, Website, Location, Birthday) but leaves "About Me" section alone?

Comment: 3 years old with no official response? /sigh

Comment: Join the club! But yeah, if it didn't get attention back  then....